# Realizar en view una consulta a dos tablas para que se muestren en una página

Tags: python, django, orm

Utilizo django 1.11.4

**view.py**:

```
def hist_list(request, id):
        histo = historial_clinico.objects.all()
        historial = histo[0]
        recetas = receta.objects.select_related().filter(paciente=historial.id)
        return render('catalogos/historial/historia_clinica.html', {'historial':histo,'recetas':recetas})
```

**models.py**:

```
class paciente(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    peso = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    talla = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre


class historial_clinico(models.Model):
    medico = models.ForeignKey(medico)
    paciente = models.ForeignKey(paciente)
    fecha_alta = models.DateField() 
    contenido = models.TextField()
    fecha_ult = models.DateField()

class receta(models.Model):
     medico = models.ForeignKey(medico)
    paciente = models.ForeignKey(paciente)
    fecha_receta = models.DateField()
    contenido = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.paciente
```

mi **html**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% if historial %}    
{% for historia in historial %}
<h1 style="color: #1F1296;">Historial Clínico del paciente {{ historia.paciente }} {{ historia.paciente.apellidos }}</h1> <br>
<div class="container-fluid">
<label style="color: #1F1296; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;">Medico: </label> <label style="color: #1F1296;">{{ historia.medico }} {{ historia.medico.apellidos }} - {{ historia.medico.especialidad }}</label><br>
<label style="color: #1F1296; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;">Ultima consulta: </label> <label style="color: #1F1296;">{{ historia.fecha_ult }}</label>
<div>
    <label style="color: #1F1296; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;">Consultas: </label> <br>
    <label style="color: #1F1296;">{{ historia.contenido }} </label>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <h1>No hay registro del historial</h1>

{% endif %}


<table class="table table-striped">
<thead style="color: #1F1296; font-weight: bold;">
    <tr>            
        <td>Num</td>
        <td>Paciente</td>
        <td>Fecha Receta</td>
        <td>Contenido</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>     
{% if recetas %} 

{% for receta in recetas %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ receta.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ receta.paciente }} {{ receta.paciente.apellidos }}</td>
        <td>{{ receta.fecha_receta }}</td>
        <td>{{ receta.contenido }}</td>
    </tr>
 {% endfor %}

 {% else %}
    <h1>No hay registro de Recetas</h1>

 {% endif %}
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'listar-pacientes' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></span> Regresar</a>
 </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Lo que necesito es que mande a llamar el historial_clinico, pero a la vez me muestre cuantas recetas tiene ese paciente.

---

**Edición:**

He intentado implementar la solución que plantea @GermanAlzate en su respuesta, pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
TypeError at /catalogos/pacientes/historial/1/

hist_list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalogos/pacientes/historial/1/
Django Version:     1.11.4
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

hist_list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Exception Location:     C:\Users\Kike-Lap\Envs\prueba\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py in _wrapped_view, line 23
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Kike-Lap\Envs\prueba\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     2.7.13
Python Path:    

 ['c:\\Sistemas\\prueba',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\Scripts',
 'c:\\python27\\Lib',
 'c:\\python27\\DLLs',
 'c:\\python27\\Lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib\\site-packages\\mysql_python-1.2.5-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib\\site-packages\\south-1.0.2-py2.7.egg']
```

Edicion 2 quitando el id

Con la solución que me planteaste @GermanAlzate

TypeError at /catalogos/pacientes/historial/1/

```
hist_list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalogos/pacientes/historial/1/
Django Version:     1.11.4
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

hist_list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Exception Location:     C:\Users\Kike-Lap\Envs\prueba\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py in _wrapped_view, line 23
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Kike-Lap\Envs\prueba\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     2.7.13
Python Path:    

      ['c:\\Sistemas\\prueba',
      'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
      'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\DLLs',
      'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib',
      'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib\\plat-win',
      'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib\\lib-tk',
      'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\Scripts',
      'c:\\python27\\Lib',
      'c:\\python27\\DLLs',
      'c:\\python27\\Lib\\lib-tk',
      'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba',
      'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib\\site-packages',
      'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib\\site-packages\\mysql_python-1.2.5-py2.7-win32.egg',
      'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib\\site-packages\\south-1.0.2-py2.7.egg']
```

urls.py   No son todas pero ahi menciono el de historial, q es el de pacientes/historial

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^pacientes/nuevo$', login_required(pacientes_new),name="pacientes-new"),
url(r'^pacientes/listar$', login_required(pacientes_list),name="listar-pacientes"),
url(r'^pacientes/editar/(?P<id>\d+)/$', login_required(pacientes_edit), name="editar-pacientes"),
url(r'^pacientes/eliminar/(?P<id>\d+)/$', login_required(pacientes_del), name="del-pacientes"),
url(r'^pacientes/historial/(?P<id>\d+)/$', login_required(hist_list), name="historial-paciente"),
```

Editar 3. Agregando la modificación

```
TypeError at /catalogos/pacientes/historial/2/

coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, paciente found

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalogos/pacientes/historial/2/
Django Version:     1.11.4
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, paciente found

Exception Location:     C:\Users\Kike-Lap\Envs\prueba\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in __repr__, line 589
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Kike-Lap\Envs\prueba\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     2.7.13
Python Path:    

['c:\\Sistemas\\prueba',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\Scripts',
 'c:\\python27\\Lib',
 'c:\\python27\\DLLs',
 'c:\\python27\\Lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib\\site-packages\\mysql_python-1.2.5-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\Kike-Lap\\Envs\\prueba\\lib\\site-packages\\south-1.0.2-py2.7.egg']
```

Comment: El error que obtienes no hace parte de mi respuesta, es simplemente porque agregaste un nuevo argumento a la función, fijate que debe ser `def hist_list(request)` y no `def hist_list(request, id)`

Comment: de igual manera me aparece el error siguiente

Comment: Si tienes un nuevo error, debe ser por tus urls, te recomendaria que las pusieras para saber como poder ayudarte

Comment: las he agregado

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta

Comment: el error que me envia, editar 3

Comment: Usas python 2 o python3?

Comment: uso la ver- python 2.7

Comment: Hola German, fijate que me puse a moverle y mande a imprimir el valor id y veo q no me esta recogiendo la id, esto imprime:  <QuerySet [<historialclinico: Prueba de consulta fecha 9 septiembre>]> que corresponde al contenido, pero no se por que razon hace eso, cambie de historial_clinico a historialclinico, ya realice los cambios, lo que me intriga es q al enviar a otro lado si envia el id, voy a editar mi pregunta para que lo puedas ver

Comment: ya me manda el id

Comment: pero no puedo realizar la consulta

Answer (score 0):

Creo que primeramente tu consulta no es del todo funcional, porque estas buscando las recetas a partir del id de una historia clínica, y no a partir del id del paciente, tal como tienes en tus modelos, te recomendaría cambiar la consulta por algo así:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
def hist_list(request, id):
    historiales = historial_clinico.objects.all()
    historial = get_object_or_404(historiales, id=id)
    recetas = historial.paciente.receta_set.all()  # aquí obtienes las recetas
    return render('catalogos/historial/historia_clinica.html', {'historiales': historiales, 'recetas': recetas})
```

De esa forma podrías solucionar el problema que veo, el resto, no lo logro comprender, no sé si te refieres a mostrar todas las recetas de a cuerdo a las historias que muestras o a las personas de esas historias.

Comment: hola, gracias por la respuesta lo voy a tomar en cuenta, en el html, despliego el paciente y todas sus recetas que ha tenido, un paciente tiene muchas recetas

Comment: Lo que veo es que siempre estas usando el primer paciente, deberías considerar anidad el for de las recetas, dentro del primer for (el de las historias), para así poder usar el paciente de cada historial, y no el mismo paciente